# Cakephp SQL Error 1064

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm getting below error when I view the index page of my petitions controller. This has been just baked...I'm not sure what this means although I suspect that this is related to table name not being plural in SQL as the table name is Petitions adhering to cake's naming conventions... Any ideas guys?

```
 SELECT `Petition`.`random_string`, `Petition`.`diary_number`, `Petition`.`group`, `Petition`.`created`, `Petition`.`modified`, `Petition`.`petitioner_type`, `Petition`.`signed`, `Petition`.`project_desc`, `Petition`.`amount_suggested`, `Petition`.`amount_accepted`, `Petition`.`project_type`, `Petition`.`project_decision`, `Petition`.`evaluation`, `Petition`.`admin_comments`, `Petition`.`commentator_comments`, `Petition`.`q1_petitioner`, `Petition`.`q1_partners`, `Petition`.`q1_regcode`, `Petition`.`q1_responsible`, `Petition`.`q1_position`, `Petition`.`q1_address`, `Petition`.`q1_zipcode`, `Petition`.`q1_city`, `Petition`.`q1_phone`, `Petition`.`q1_gsm`, `Petition`.`q1_email`, `Petition`.`q2_project_name`, `Petition`.`q2_target_group`, `Petition`.`q2_project_goal`, `Petition`.`q2_newones`, `Petition`.`q2_newgroups`, `Petition`.`q2_organizers`, `Petition`.`q2_donations`, `Petition`.`q2_type`, `Petition`.`q3_amount`, `Petition`.`q3_purpose`, `Petition`.`q3_account_number`, `Petition`.`q3_receiver`, `Petition`.`q4_sports`, `Petition`.`q4_participates`, `Petition`.`q4_places`, `Petition`.`q4_schedule`, `Petition`.`q4_marketing`, `Petition`.`q4_directors`, `Petition`.`q4_monitoring`, `Petition`.`q4_support`, `Petition`.`q4_collaboration`, `Petition`.`q5_costs`, `Petition`.`q5_costs_desc`, `Petition`.`q5_income`, `Petition`.`q5_income_desc`, `Petition`.`q5_invisible`, `Petition`.`s1_question1`, `Petition`.`s1_question2`, `Petition`.`s1_question3`, `Petition`.`s1_question4`, `Petition`.`s1_question5`, s1_question., `Petition`.`s2_question1`, `Petition`.`s2_question2`, `Petition`.`s2_question_3`, `Petition`.`s3_question1`, s3_question2., `Petition`.`s4_question1`, `Petition`.`s4_question2`, `Petition`.`s5_question1`, s5_question2. FROM `petitions` AS `Petition` WHERE 1 = 1 LIMIT 20   1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' `Petition`.`s2_question1`, `Petition`.`s2_question2`, `Petition`.`s2_question_3' at line 1            0
```

Comment: Can you paste the full query here, and possibly part of code that generates it? It's impossible to say from that segment.

Comment: I've included full query as requested. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes, if the table name is Petitions then SQL code that attempts to select values from a table named Petition, is not going to work.  My understanding of Cakephp conventions is that it wants all tables to be be lowercase, so perhaps this is throwing off its inflector?  See:  http://book.cakephp.org/view/1478/Inflector.

Comment: That's right, but Cake creates the queries as `SELECT Petition.id, ... FROM petitions AS Petition`

Comment: I got it guys! It was "s1_question...", "s2_question...", "s3_question..." columns which were the issues. MySQL has issues with "..." names so I got rid of "..." and it's working fine!

Below is the code I used:

    ALTER TABLE `petitions` CHANGE `s1_question...` `s1_question` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
    CHANGE `s3_question2...` `s3_question2` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
    CHANGE `s5_question2...` `s5_question2` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL 

Hope this helps someone! I learnt something today though!