# please help me fix sql query in cake php

Tags: sql, cakephp

I am wondering where to write select query is written in cake php I only see following code in controller

```
function getpages($position = 'top') {
        return $this->Page->find('all', array('conditions' => 'Page.'.$position.'_show > 0', 'order' => 'Page.'.$position.'_order ASC'));
}
```

and its giving following error

> Warning (512) SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `` 'FROM  AS `Page`   WHERE `Page`.`top_show` > 0   ORDER BY `Page`.`top_order` ASC' ``

and

```
$this->set('categories', $this->Category->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Category.parent_id' => $category['Category']['id']), 'order' => array('Category.name' => 'asc'))));
```

is giving following error

> SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''

please tell me how to fix it

Comment: Put this code `echo $this->element('sql_dump')` in the view (layout) file and Debug the actual error in the sql query

Comment: layout file have following file ja json rss and  admin.ctp, user.ctpdefault,ctp  anyway all error in www.bidknight.com  please visit and help me

Comment: check for the `table name` [need to be in lowercase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805610/cakephp-sql-error-1064)

Comment: Also have you loaded the `Category` model before executing the code

Comment: if (empty($category)) {
   $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid Category.', true));
   $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
  }
  $this->set('category', $category);
  $this->set('parents', $this->Category->getpath($id));
  $this->set('categories', $this->Category->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Category.parent_id' => $category['Category']['id']), 'order' => array('Category.name' => 'asc'))));

Comment: is this `Category` a table name in `'Category.parent_id'`?

Comment: no table name is categories. what changes i need to perform i m very new to cake php

Comment: can you try one thing. Just remove the `Category` from the `'Category.name'` and `'Category.parent_id'`. Means it could be `'parent_id'`. Please check if this works.

Comment: real code is  function getlist($parent = null, $find = 'list', $count = null){
  if($parent == 'parent') {
   if($find !== 'all') {
   $this->Category->recursive = -1;
   }
   /* $categories = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Category  where `Category`.`parent_id` = 0   ORDER BY `Category`.`name` asc   ');
   echo $categories ; */
 $categories =  $this->Category-> find($find, array( 'conditions' => array('Category.parent_id' => 0), 'order' => array('Category.name' => 'asc')));

Comment: i changed it to category.parent_id to parent id and name but still not working

Comment: i dont get it about this 'array('Category.parent_id' => 0),' is the value of `$category['Category']['id']` is zero? it should not be.

Please do the following steps:-> 



first you try to execute this code
$this->Category->find('all');
if you are getting the correct response than execute this
$this->Category->find('all', array('conditions' => array('categories.parent_id' => $category['Category']['id'])))); ...

and the value $category['Category']['id'] should be >= 1.

Comment: hope it already been there (To load model) $this->Loadmodel('Category');

Comment: not working wait i send u whole code

Comment: function view($id = null) {
  if(empty($id)) { redirect to page
  }
  $this->set('category', $category);
  $this->set('parents', $this->Category->getpath($id));$this->set('categories', $this->Category->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Category.parent_id' => $category['Category']['id']), 'order' => array('Category.name' => 'asc'))));

Comment: function getlist($parent = null, $find = 'list', $count = null){
  if($parent == 'parent') {
   if($find !== 'all') {
   $this->Category->recursive = -1;
   }
                        $this->Loadmodel('Category');
   /* $categories = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Category  where `Category`.`parent_id` = 0   ORDER BY `Category`.`name` asc   ');
   echo $categories ; */
 $categories =  $this->Category-> find($find, array( 'conditions' => array('Category.parent_id' => 0), 'order' => array('Category.name' => 'asc')));

} else {
   $categories = $this->Category->generateTreeList(null, null, null, '-');

Comment: if i do find all i got following error    SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM  AS `Category`   WHERE 1 = 1' at line 1 [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 521]

Query: SELECT FROM AS `Category` WHERE 1 = 1

Comment: http://www.bidknight.com/ u can visit and check please

Comment: Check this: function view($id = null) {
    $this->Loadmodel('Category');
    
    if(empty($id)) { 
        redirect to page 
    } 
    $this->set('category', $category); // what is $category??
    $this->set('parents', $this->Category->getpath($id));
    //if $category is already here 
    if(!empty(category['Category']['id'])) {
        $this->set('categories', 
                $this->Category->find('all', 
                    array(
                        'conditions' => array('parent_id' => $category['Category']['id'])
                    )
                ));
    }
}

Comment: can i have the category model files content?

Comment: <?php
 class Category extends AppModel {

  var $name = 'Category';

  var $actsAs = array(
   'Containable',
   'Tree',
   'ImageUpload' => array(
    'image' => array(
     'required'      => false,
     'directory'           => 'img/category_images/',
     'allowed_mime'        => array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png'),
     'allowed_extension'   => array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif'),
     'allowed_size'        => 2000000,
     'random_filename'     => true,
     'image' => array(
      'create_thumb'    => true,

Comment: var $belongsTo = array(
   'ParentCategory' => array(
    'className'  => 'Category',
    'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
   )
  );

  var $hasMany = array(
   'Auction' => array(
    'className'  => 'Auction',
    'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
    'dependent'  => false
   ),
   'ChildCategory' => array(
    'className'  => 'Category',
    'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
    'dependent'  => false
   )
  );

  var $validate = array(
   'name' => array(
    'rule' => array('minLength', 1),
          'message' => 'Name is a required field.'
         ),

Comment: ),
         'parent_id' => array(
    'rule' => 'parentCheck',
    'message' => 'The Parent Category cannot be the current category.'
         ),
  );

  // this makes sure the parent category isn't the current ID
  function parentCheck() {
   if(!empty($this->data['Category']['id']) && (!empty($this->data['Category']['parent_id']))) {
    if($this->data['Category']['id'] == $this->data['Category']['parent_id']) {
     return false;
    }
   }
   return true;
  }
 }
?>

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to write query:

```
$this->set('categories', $this->Category->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Category.parent_id' => $category['Category']['id']), 
'order' => 'Category.name ASC'))));
```

Comment: <?php
class CategoriesController extends AppController {

 var $name = 'Categories';

 function beforeFilter(){
  parent::beforeFilter();

  if(!empty($this->Auth)){
   $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view', 'getlist');
  }
 }

 function index() {
   $this->Category->recursive = 0;
   $this->paginate = array('conditions' => array('Category.parent_id' => 0), 'order' => array('Category.name' => 'asc'));
  $this->set('categories', $this->paginate());
  $this->pageTitle = __('Categories', true);

Comment: please describe query for pages to    function getpages($position = 'top') {
        return $this->Page->find('all', array('conditions' => 'Page.'.$position.'_show > 0', 'order' => 'Page.'.$position.'_order ASC'));
}

Comment: $param= $position.'_show';                                            $this->Page->find('all', array('conditions' =>array(" $param>" => '0'), 'order' => "$param ASC"));

Comment: SELECT `Categories`.`id`, categories`.name FROM categories  AS `Category`   WHERE `Category`.`parent_id` = 0   ORDER BY `Category`.`name` ASC

Comment: pleade help me write sql query in cake php format my sql query is SELECT Categories.id, categories`.name FROM categories AS Category WHERE Category.parent_id = 0 ORDER BY Category.name ASC

Comment: $this->Category->find('all','fields' =>array('Category.id','Category.name'),'conditions' =>array('Category.parent_id' => 0), 'order' => 'Category.name ASC' ); I will suggest you to search google first before asking questions here. This is very easy to find and learn.

Comment: it is giving following error  syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in /home/content/e/p/p/eppers/html/knight/app/controllers/categories_controller.php on line 76

Comment: $this->Category->find('all',array('fields' =>array('Category.id','Category.name'),'conditions' =>array('Category.parent_id' => 0), 'order' => 'Category.name ASC' ));

Comment: SELECT `Category`.`id`, `Category`.`name` FROM  AS `Category`   WHERE `Category`.`parent_id` = 0   ORDER BY `Category`.`name` ASC  please tell me what to write in model or view to fix it :( this query is giving me trouble from last week :(

Comment: Did you load model in your controller? What is the error you get?

Comment: Warning (512): SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS `Category`   WHERE `Category`.`parent_id` = 0   ORDER BY `Category`.`name` AS' at line 1 [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 521

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31295/discussion-between-cartina-and-user2380512)

Answer (score 0):

first this is your correct format

```
  $this->set('categories', $this->Category->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Category.parent_id' => $category['Category']['id']), 
'order' => 'Category.name ASC'))));
```

second add this two in the category model class

```
var $useTable = 'Categories'; // Actual table name
var $alias = 'Category';
```

This is what i have with my understanding.

Comment: select * from pages where pages.bottom_show>0 order by pages.bottom_order asc; can u convert into cake php query

Comment: // Put the code in controller
$this->Loadmodel('page'); // Need to have page.model as 
$query['conditions'] = array('pages.bottom_show > 0');
$query['order'] = array('bottom_order', 'asc');
$this->page->find('all', $query);


page.model
class page extends AppModel {
    // var $useTable = 'pages';
    
}------- Assuming page.model do not have any belongsto, hasone/many etc. relationship. If it has then you have to check hot to execute find without them.

Comment: thanks its working perfectly can you please tell me same thing for category too  what changes i need to perform in category .model and controller

Comment: 'parent_id' => array(
    'rule' => 'parentCheck',
    'message' => 'The Parent Category cannot be the current category.'
         ),
  );

  // this makes sure the parent category isn't the current ID
  function parentCheck() {


   if(!empty($this->data['Category']['id']) && (!empty($this->data['Category']['parent_id']))) {
    if($this->data['Category']['id'] == $this->data['Category']['parent_id']) {
     return false;
    }
   }
   return true;
  }
 }
?> this is category model function